# Plugins Chart.js mostar los valores en la grafica de barras

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hola estoy trabajando con Chart.js para mostrar diferentes gráficas, en la gráfica de barras que la que me lleva el por ciento cumplido me hace falta mostrar el valor encima de la barra, alguién me podria ayudar, creo que hay que trabajar en las opciones con onComplete pero no tengo el conocimiento para hacerlo.

```js
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio"],

  datasets: [{

      fillColor: "#6b9dfa",
      strokeColor: "#ffffff",
      highlightFill: "#1864f2",
      highlightStroke: "#ffffff",
      data: [90, 30, 10, 80, 15, 5, 15]

    },
    {

      fillColor: "#e9e225",
      strokeColor: "#ffffff",
      highlightFill: "#ee7f49",
      highlightStroke: "#ffffff",
      data: [40, 50, 70, 40, 85, 55, 15]

    }

  ]

}
var ctx3 = document.getElementById("chart-rea3").getContext("2d");
window.myPie = new Chart(ctx3).Bar(barChartData, {
  responsive: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart-rea3" class="pie"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basandome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31632707/3045491) he creado una variable `options` que contiene el evento `onAnimationComplete` y recorre cada columna añadiendo un texto arriba con el valor.

Si quieres otra posicion, has de modificar el valor de `x` e `y` en esta linea:

```
ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
```

Además puse también la opción `showTooltips: false` para que cuando pases el raton no muestre la informacion porque ya está puesta encima de las columnas.

```js
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio"],

  datasets: [{

      fillColor: "#6b9dfa",
      strokeColor: "#ffffff",
      highlightFill: "#1864f2",
      highlightStroke: "#ffffff",
      data: [90, 30, 10, 80, 15, 5, 15]

    },
    {

      fillColor: "#e9e225",
      strokeColor: "#ffffff",
      highlightFill: "#ee7f49",
      highlightStroke: "#ffffff",
      data: [40, 50, 70, 40, 85, 55, 15]

    }

  ]

}

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  showTooltips: false,
  onAnimationComplete: function() {

    var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
    ctx.font = this.scale.font;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

    this.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
      dataset.bars.forEach(function(bar) {
        ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
      });
    })
  }
};

var ctx3 = document.getElementById("chart-rea3").getContext("2d");
window.myPie = new Chart(ctx3).Bar(barChartData, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart-rea3" class="pie"></canvas>
```

Comment: Estoy haciendo lo mismo pero en la version 2.7.2 pero no me funciona alguien sabe algo?

Comment: Buenas @Juanzu no estoy al tanto de versiones, qué errores te da?

Comment: no me muestra los valores por encima. Pero ya lo logre solucionar agregando otro codigo para la version que estoy usando.

Comment: @Juanzu me alegra que lo solucionaras. si crees que es util para el resto puedes añadirlo como respuesta nueva mencionando los cambios en la nueva version !! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Aqui esta la solucion para los que estan utilizando las version 2.7.2 de charts.js

[no pinta grafica dinamica bar de charts js en laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/399491/no-pinta-grafica-dinamica-bar-de-charts-js-en-laravel)