# no pinta grafica dinamica bar de charts js en laravel

Tags: laravel-5, mariadb, chart.js

Estoy intentando generar graficos tipo bar con mi BD en array pero no me pinta nada, aparece en blanco. En mi consulta estoy trayendo el total de saldo y abonos agrupado por mes. Estoy utilizando laravel 5.6

Este es la ruta `web.php`

```
Route::get('reporte/barra', 'ReportesController@barra');
```

Est es el contralador donde hago la consulta a la bd `ReportesController.php`

```
 public function barra()
    {

        $abonos = Abono::select(DB::raw("sum(saldo_abono) as saldo, sum(cantidad) as  tabono, MONTHNAME(fecha) as mes"))
            ->groupBy("mes")->get();

            return view('cuentas.reporte.barra',['abonos'=>$abonos]);

    }
```

esta es la estructura de la tabla que hago la consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de la vista `barra.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <h3>
            Reporte de abonos
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card card-stats card-round">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-title">DEPARTICION DE DINERO</div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="chart-container">
      <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
@push('script')
{{-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script> --}}
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/plugin/chart.js/chart.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/plugin/jquery.sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/plugin/chart-circle/circles.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/plugin/datatables/datatables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
var myBarChart = new Chart(barChart, {
      type: 'bar',
        data: {
        labels: 
          //generar dinamicamente el label del mes
          @foreach ($abonos as $abono)
          ["{{$abono->mes}}"]
          @endforeach

        datasets: [{
        label: "$",
        backgroundColor: '#FFCE06',
        borderColor: '#FFCE06',
        data:
        @foreach ($abonos as $abono)
         ["{{$abono->saldo}}, {{$abono->tabono}}"]
        @endforeach
    
        }],
      },
        options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
    }
    }]
    },
    }
 });

</script>
@endpush
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me puse a investigar y logre obtener la solucion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var datos = @json($abonos);

mes=[];
saldo=[];
abono=[];

datos.map(o=>{
   mes.push(o.mes)
   saldo.push(o.saldo)
   abono.push(o.tabono);
})

//quitar tooltips
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;

var myBarChart = new Chart(barChart, {
    type:'bar',
    
    data:{
        labels: mes,
        datasets: [{
        label:"saldo",
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: saldo

        },{
        label:"abono",
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: abono
        }
      ],
        options:{
        responsive: true,
            layout: {
                padding: {
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 15,
                bottom: 0
                }
            },
            animation: {
            duration : 1,
                onComplete : function() {
                var chartInstance = this.chart,
                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
        
                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle,
                Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
        
                    this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
                    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                        meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                            if (dataset.data[index] > 0) {
                            var data = dataset.data[index];
                            ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y);
                            }
                         });
                     });
                }
            }
        }

    }
});
</script>
```